# How do I change the plot so that it starts at the left corner and ends and the right corner (I hope this make sense)

Tags: python, pandas

I am asked to reproduce the plot as accurate as possible. This is the plot that I have to reproduce

[image]

Here is the code that I use to plot the graph

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18,5))
plt.plot (df.Volume, color='black', label = 'APPL')
plt.plot (df.Volume_moving, '--', color = 'black')
plt.plot (df2.Volume, color='red', label = 'GOOG')
plt.plot (df2.Volume_moving, '--', color = 'red')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0,50000000])
plt.legend(loc='upper right',fontsize =12);
plt.xlabel ('Days since Oct 15th', fontsize =15)
plt.ylabel ('Volume Traded(Million Shares)', fontsize= 15)
```

currently my graph looks like this
[image]

What I wanted to ask was is it possible for the data to start at the left corner and ends at the right like the example.

In addition to that if you guys dont mind, I would like to ask how can I get the border around my legend like the example. And how do I write the correlation on the top left like the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try:

```
axes.set_xlim([df.index[0], df.index[-1]])
```

Comment: maybe pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried the datetime, it does not give what i want. And for the error from the first code its the 

axes.set_xlim([[df.index[0], df.index[-1]])
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

thank you for your reply, and Im sorry for not getting back to you earlier.

Comment: allright... there was a bracket mistake in my answer... I edited it... try it this way!